# Keyboard Shortcuts enabled but not working KDE Plasma

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde

I'm currently running Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.
While I'm not sure if this problem has always existed, I'm pretty sure it only showed up since I got this thing up and running again (last night; it just wasn't connected. Just no need for the system).

For some reason, when I'm editing any type of text, be it source code, normal text documents, even text within Chrome and KDE itself, the following keyboard shortcuts aren't working:

- <kbd>CTRL(+SHIFT)+L-ARROW</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL(+SHIFT)+R-ARROW</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL+BACKSPACE</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL+DEL</kbd> works)

While it might seem like a minor nuisance, this is actually quite debilitating when writing source code and anything with more than a couple lines of text.

I've checked in the KDE System Settings if the shortcuts are enabled and active:
[image: KDE System Settings]

As you can see in the image, they're all active and set to the correct values.

**I've not tried setting anything in .bashrc, .inputrc or any other files.**

How can I re-enable these shortcuts, so they work system-wide and not just in the Terminal (as this is what I assume pfushing around in the aforementioned files does)?

Comment: Is the image you posted edited in any way (other than being cropped)? I'm asking because several intermediate keybindings seem to be missing.

Comment: No, the image is just cropped

Comment: Well, I too have Kubuntu 18.04 (fully updated) and [this is a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBdfn.png) of what I see. Note the intermediate shortcuts present in my image absent from yours.